# Concaternar en PDO PHP

Tags: php, html, pdo

Buen día comunidad, tengo una pequeña duda estoy tratando de mostrar unos datos, pero al momento de mostrar en la tabla, los campos que estoy tratando de concatenar, los junta por completo es decir se muestra de esta manera "JosePerez", tienen alguna sugerencia?

```
        foreach($studentInformation as $key=>$element) {  
        
            $studentInfo[] = array(

            $element['ID'],

            $element['nombre'].$element['apellido_pat'].$element['apellido_mat'], 

            $element['telefono'], 

            $element['email'], 

            $element['rama'],
            
            $element['fecha_nac'], 
            
            $element['edad']

            );    

        }

        // Extraer datos  

        $json['studentData'] = array(

        "draw"        =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),

        "recordsTotal"    =>  $totalResult,

        "recordsFiltered"   =>    $Totalres,  

        "data"          =>  $studentInfo

        );

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        echo json_encode($json['studentData'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 

    }
```

Se me ocurre poner un espacio en los campos de la base de datos, pero no se si es conveniente o existe alguna forma de concatenar agregando los espacios

Comment: Coloca un espacio entre cada cadena: `$nombre = $nombre . " " . $apellido;`

Comment: Gracias bro, funcionó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba este código

```php
$studentInfo[] = array(

            $element['ID'],

            $element['nombre']." ".$element['apellido_pat']." ".$element['apellido_mat'], 

            $element['telefono'], 

            $element['email'], 

            $element['rama'],
            
            $element['fecha_nac'], 
            
            $element['edad']

            );
```

Comment: Gracias bro, funcionó

Answer (score 2):

La manera de concatenar elementos en PHP es con un . (punto)

```
$nombre = $var1. " " . $var2;
echo $nombre // output: variable1 variable2
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato bro